# Объединить синонимичные метки {“карта”, “карты”, "maps"}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [карта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0) - 20 вопросов;
- [карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b) - 48 вопросов;
- [maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maps) - 72 вопроса.

(по состоянию на 18.03.2017)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Comment: С [tag:map] не пройдет, т.к. метка по большей части используется для контейнеров, а не карт.

Comment: @alexolut , ну если так, то ей нужно какое-то соответствующее однозначное описание...

Comment: описания безусловно нужны.

Comment: @alexolut, предложил описание для [map].

Comment: @Arhad в текущей редакции пришлось отклонить.

Comment: @Arhad предложил [другую](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/150907).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метки объединены, основной выбрана [карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b).